# AWS - notify desktop application by SNS or other mechanism

Tags: amazon-web-services, architecture, cloud, desktop-application, amazon-sns

I am new to AWS and I am looking for a solution for my architecture. My backend is hosting on AWS and I have hundreds of desktop applications on MAC and Windows. Is it possible to use SNS to notify every desktop app when something happens on my backend? For example, some events occurred, etc. If yes, how looks desktop app authorization? If no, what are the possible ways to achieve this result?

I decided to ask a question because I couldn't find any solution inside the documentation. There are only options connected with mobile devices which is not my use case. Thanks in advance!